# How to save the value of a radio button to local storage? How to Resume it?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a `radio button` to save sex. I tried to store in the local storage but then I do not echo to recover the value

I have implemented it so:

```
var inputsesso= document.getElementsByName("sesso");
localStorage.setItem("sesso", inputsesso.value);


 var sesso = localStorage.getItem("sesso");
 document.getElementsByName("sesso").value=sesso;
```

## html

```
   <label class="radio-container m-r-45">Male
    <input type="radio" id="sesso" checked="checked" name="gender" 
        required value="M">
    <span class="checkmark"></span>

    </label>
    <label class="radio-container">Female
    <input type="radio"  id="sesso" name="gender" required value="F">
    <span class="checkmark"></span>
    </label>
```

where is the error?

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```js
// get value from localstorage
var sesso = localStorage.getItem("sesso");

// if key sesso exists in localstorage
if (sesso) {
  let radioByValue = document.querySelector("input[value='" + sesso + "']");
  radioByValue.checked = true
}

// target all radios by name([ES6 feature] using spread operator to iterate it)
var inputsesso = [...document.getElementsByName("gender")];

// add listener on change value for each radio
inputsesso.forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener("change", function() {
    localStorage.setItem("sesso", this.value);
  });
});
```

```html
<label class="radio-container m-r-45">Male
    <input type="radio" checked="checked" name="gender" required value="M">
    <span class="checkmark"></span>

</label>
<label class="radio-container">Female
    <input type="radio" name="gender" required value="F">
    <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
```